# Creating GitHub readme build status badge, based on commit build status?

Tags: javascript, github, markdown, badge, readme

### Context

I would like to eliminate the manual exporting of build status badges that my CI does to GitHub. To do this, I intend to create/use a build status badge in the `README.md` of repo `repo_a`, that reflects the build status of the head commit `head_commit_c` of branch `branch_b` status of the head of a branch. This build status of `head_commit_c` is already set by my self-hosted CI, so I hope I won't also have to output the build status badge (anymore).

### Question

*(How) can one set a build status badge in a `README.md` of a GitHub repository `repo_a` with branch `branch_b` based on the latest(HEAD) commit `commit_c` of that branch?*

### Related example

[In this repository](https://github.com/Naereen/badges) I saw that some markdown badges contain a `.js`. I assumed this is somehow able to retrieve some property  of a GitHub repository, for example the amount of stars:

```
[![GitHub branches](https://badgen.net/github/branches/Naereen/Strapdown.js)](https://github.com/Naereen/Strapdown.js/)
```

So I thought there might be a related `.js` file that parses the latest GitHub commit status and converts it into an `.svg`/badge.

### Attempt I

Based on the documentation linked in the comments, I tried:

```
![example branch parameter](https://github.com/github/docs/actions/workflows/main.yml/badge.svg?branch=main)
```

Which returns:
[image]

I think this is because it refers to a [workflow file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge#using-the-workflow-file-name) which does not exist in this case, as I run my own CI.

So if this workflow file named `main.yml` can directly link the build status result of a branch, to the latest commit status in that branch, I imagine one could add such a workflow file. I did not yet determine whether this indeed is the case, and if yes, how.

### Note

So I do not mean a link that parses the url of a specific commit, but an automatically updated link to the latest commit build status.

Comment: Your *related example* returns `image/svg+xml` and does not execute any JavaScript. `Strapdown.js` is just a string parameter of this API and their backend calculates an SVG. GitHub offers branch-specific workflow status badges according to the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge#using-the-branch-parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I incorrectly assumed the *related  example* executed JavaScript, and I was unaware I made that assumption. I adjusted the question to reflect your insight. Thank you for referring to the relevant docs segment! I've tried to implement the example given, however, I did not yet resolve how to deal with the `workflow file` as I run my own CI, instead of using GitHub actions. I would expect the `.yml` only refers to build status results of GitHub actions, instead of to the commit build status directly. However, I have not found if that's true or not.

Comment: If you are using your own CI, you need to find a way to get the badge from this CI system and then use the appropriate URL in the readme.

Comment: @Matt, that would be optimal, however, for the time being, I thought this sub-optimal strategy of getting the build status badge directly from the commit sha would be acceptable.